# nestjs:how to delete redis cache with prefix in typeorm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, redis-cache

I have a service class with `create,list`,and `update` methods to modify entity

I set the redis cache in list methods,and the cache key is `list_cache_1,list_cache_2,...`

my question is, how to delete all releated caches in `create` or `update` methods, like

```
this.connection.queryResultCache.remove([`list_cache:*`]);
```

Answer (score 1):

when you set a "cache id" via QueryBuilder:

```
const users = await connection
    .createQueryBuilder(User, "user")
    .where("user.isAdmin = :isAdmin", { isAdmin: true })
    .cache("list_cache_1", 25000)
    .getMany();
```

Or with Repository:

```
const users = await connection
    .getRepository(User)
    .find({
        where: { isAdmin: true },
        cache: {
            id: "list_cache_1",
            milliseconds: 25000
        }
    });
```

then, get the connection object and remove as below

```
import { getConnection } from "typeorm";

const connection = getConnection();
await connection.queryResultCache.remove([`list_cache_1`]);
```

however, i'm not aware of a typeorm method to remove list_cache_* with wildcard.